# How to read in unusual date\time format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a small df with a date\time column using a format I have never seen.

Pandas reads it in as an object even if I use parse_dates, and to_datetime() chokes on it.

The dates in the column are formatted as such:

```
2019/12/29 GMT+8 18:00
2019/12/15 GMT+8 05:00
```

I think the best approach is using a date parsing pattern. Something like this:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv(infile, parse_dates=['datetime'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

But I simply do not know how to approach this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The datatime format for UTC is very specific for converting the offset.

  - [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)
  - The format must be `+` or `-` and then `00:00`
  - Use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to backfill the `0`s between the sign and the integer

    - `+08:00` or `-08:00` or `+10:00` or `-10:00`

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2019/12/29 GMT+8 18:00', '2019/12/15 GMT+8 05:00', '2019/12/15 GMT+10 05:00', '2019/12/15 GMT-10 05:00']})

# display(df)
datetime
2019/12/29 GMT+8 18:00
2019/12/15 GMT+8 05:00
2019/12/15 GMT+10 05:00
2019/12/15 GMT-10 05:00

# fix the format
df.datetime = df.datetime.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x[0] + x[2] + x[1][3:].zfill(3) + ':00')

# convert to a utc datetime
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime, format='%Y/%m/%d%H:%M%z', utc=True)

# display(df)
datetime
2019-12-29 10:00:00+00:00
2019-12-14 21:00:00+00:00
2019-12-14 19:00:00+00:00
2019-12-15 15:00:00+00:00


print(df.info())
[out]:

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype              
---  ------    --------------  -----              
 0   datetime  4 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
```

Comment: @Trenton_McKinney   Something must have been corrupt.  I deleted the data and downloaded it again and your code works.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the custom format with `GMT+8` in the middle and then subtract eight hours with `timedelta(hours=8)`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y/%m/%d GMT+8 %H:%M') - timedelta(hours=8)
df

                 Date
0 2019-12-29 10:00:00
1 2019-12-14 21:00:00
```